# Weird slow queries after update RDS from 5.7.26 to 8.0.21

Tags: mysql, query-performance, amazon-rds, mysql-8.0

We have ~500dbs having ~110 tables each. DB was running on t2.medium instance for multiple years. I noticed that IO was growing gradually and reached not really nice avg values of 220-250 iops. So we decided to update db instance to t3 gen (medium as well) and move to v8 of mysql.

Migration was done by creation ro-replica instance and promoting it to master instance. A few parameters were added but all 5.7 values were preserved (no values were changed intentionally). It was running for a 1.5 weeks (before promotion) as a slave so we ensured it works fine. After the promotion, we monitored aws resources and everything was exactly as expected — io load a little bit less than before, memory and cpu resources are consumed in pretty similar manner. General performance of our service is the same fast at that time.

After ~4 hours of working in a role of master we noticed horrible performance issues (the simplest queries to retrieve 20 rows from the table having 20 rows could took 10-20sec). We disabled all cron tasks, queue consumers, etc. We checked amount of incoming http queries and it was ~40-50% of our max values as migration was intentionally scheduled to quietest day and time. Reboot of RDS instance didn't help. A quick and dirty solution which helped to get relief is upgrade an instance to t3.large having 8gb rather than 4gb of previous one. But the weird detail here is the amount of free memory of 4.4Gb once new instance started. Obviously eventually it was wasted with caches but that took ~5 hours. Despite the fact that instance is bigger and has more memory, we still experienced multiple times more slow queries (limit is 5s) than we had before migrating to Mysql 8.0. We introduced several new indices, increased buffers/pools, number of cached table definitions — that helped a little bit, but still far from values before migration (1-3k slow queries per 24h vs less than 10).

The most weird detail now for me is queries: they don't filter millions of rows but damn slow.

[image: slow queries log]

I would see some weird pattern of slow query postponed/blocked other queries if `start_time` would mean `completion_time` :/ Totally weird to me.

Small explanation to the picture: table `set_general` has just 2 varchar columns 1-20 chars long. There are 20-80 rows in total, depending on db. Table `cron_tasks` has <10 rows and 4 varchar columns 5-10 chars long. I assume that fetching all records from such tables must be *extremely* simple and fast task.

Another page of slow logs:

[image: a lot of prepare queries]

Looks like one heavy query blocks others. Why? Also, there are a lot of `Prepare` rather than actual query which is weird to me.

Variables:

> activate_all_roles_on_login OFF
>  admin_address
>  admin_port 33062
>  admin_ssl_ca
>  admin_ssl_capath
>  admin_ssl_cert
>  admin_ssl_cipher
>  admin_ssl_crl
>  admin_ssl_crlpath
>  admin_ssl_key
>  admin_tls_ciphersuites
>  admin_tls_version TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
>  auto_generate_certs ON
>  auto_increment_increment 1
>  auto_increment_offset 1
>  autocommit ON
>  automatic_sp_privileges ON
>  avoid_temporal_upgrade OFF
>  back_log 640
>  basedir /rdsdbbin/mysql-8.0.21.R8/
>  big_tables OFF
>  bind_address *
>  binlog_cache_size 32768
>  binlog_checksum CRC32
>  binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
>  binlog_encryption OFF
>  binlog_error_action ABORT_SERVER
>  binlog_expire_logs_seconds 2592000
>  binlog_format MIXED
>  binlog_group_commit_sync_delay 0
>  binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count 0
>  binlog_gtid_simple_recovery ON
>  binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
>  binlog_order_commits ON
>  binlog_rotate_encryption_master_key_at_startup OFF
>  binlog_row_event_max_size 8192
>  binlog_row_image FULL
>  binlog_row_metadata MINIMAL
>  binlog_row_value_options
>  binlog_rows_query_log_events OFF
>  binlog_stmt_cache_size 32768
>  binlog_transaction_compression OFF
>  binlog_transaction_compression_level_zstd 3
>  binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size 25000
>  binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking COMMIT_ORDER
>  block_encryption_mode aes-128-ecb
>  bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
>  caching_sha2_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys ON
>  caching_sha2_password_private_key_path private_key.pem
>  caching_sha2_password_public_key_path public_key.pem
>  character_set_client utf8mb4
>  character_set_connection utf8mb4
>  character_set_database utf8mb4
>  character_set_filesystem utf8mb4
>  character_set_results utf8mb4
>  character_set_server utf8mb4
>  character_set_system utf8
>  character_sets_dir /rdsdbbin/mysql-8.0.21.R8/share/charsets/
>  check_proxy_users OFF
>  collation_connection utf8mb4_unicode_ci
>  collation_database utf8mb4_unicode_ci
>  collation_server utf8mb4_unicode_ci
>  completion_type NO_CHAIN
>  concurrent_insert AUTO
>  connect_timeout 10
>  core_file OFF
>  create_admin_listener_thread OFF
>  cte_max_recursion_depth 1000
>  datadir /rdsdbdata/db/
>  default_authentication_plugin mysql_native_password
>  default_collation_for_utf8mb4 utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
>  default_password_lifetime 0
>  default_storage_engine InnoDB
>  default_table_encryption OFF
>  default_tmp_storage_engine InnoDB
>  default_week_format 0
>  delay_key_write ON
>  delayed_insert_limit 100
>  delayed_insert_timeout 300
>  delayed_queue_size 1000
>  disabled_storage_engines
>  disconnect_on_expired_password ON
>  div_precision_increment 4
>  end_markers_in_json OFF
>  enforce_gtid_consistency OFF
>  eq_range_index_dive_limit 200
>  error_count 0
>  event_scheduler ON
>  expire_logs_days 0
>  explicit_defaults_for_timestamp ON
>  external_user
>  flush OFF
>  flush_time 0
>  foreign_key_checks ON
>  ft_boolean_syntax + -><()~*:""&|
>  ft_max_word_len 84
>  ft_min_word_len 4
>  ft_query_expansion_limit 20
>  ft_stopword_file (built-in)
>  general_log OFF
>  general_log_file /rdsdbdata/log/general/mysql-general.log
>  generated_random_password_length 20
>  group_concat_max_len 1024
>  group_replication_consistency EVENTUAL
>  gtid_executed
>  gtid_executed_compression_period 1000
>  gtid_mode OFF_PERMISSIVE
>  gtid_next AUTOMATIC
>  gtid_owned
>  gtid_purged
>  have_compress YES
>  have_dynamic_loading YES
>  have_geometry YES
>  have_openssl YES
>  have_profiling YES
>  have_query_cache NO
>  have_rtree_keys YES
>  have_ssl YES
>  have_statement_timeout YES
>  have_symlink DISABLED
>  histogram_generation_max_mem_size 20000000
>  host_cache_size 635
>  hostname ip-10-2-0-153
>  identity 0
>  immediate_server_version 999999
>  information_schema_stats_expiry 86400
>  init_connect
>  init_file
>  init_slave
>  innodb_adaptive_flushing ON
>  innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm 10
>  innodb_adaptive_hash_index ON
>  innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts 8
>  innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
>  innodb_api_bk_commit_interval 5
>  innodb_api_disable_rowlock OFF
>  innodb_api_enable_binlog OFF
>  innodb_api_enable_mdl OFF
>  innodb_api_trx_level 0
>  innodb_autoextend_increment 64
>  innodb_autoinc_lock_mode 2
>  innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size 134217728
>  innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown ON
>  innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF
>  innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct 25
>  innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool
>  innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file ON
>  innodb_buffer_pool_instances 8
>  innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort OFF
>  innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup ON
>  innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
>  innodb_buffer_pool_size 5368709120
>  innodb_change_buffer_max_size 25
>  innodb_change_buffering all
>  innodb_checksum_algorithm crc32
>  innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled OFF
>  innodb_commit_concurrency 0
>  innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct 5
>  innodb_compression_level 6
>  innodb_compression_pad_pct_max 50
>  innodb_concurrency_tickets 5000
>  innodb_data_file_path ibdata1:12M:autoextend
>  innodb_data_home_dir /rdsdbdata/db/innodb
>  innodb_deadlock_detect ON
>  innodb_dedicated_server OFF
>  innodb_default_row_format dynamic
>  innodb_directories
>  innodb_disable_sort_file_cache OFF
>  innodb_doublewrite ON
>  innodb_doublewrite_batch_size 16
>  innodb_doublewrite_dir
>  innodb_doublewrite_files 2
>  innodb_doublewrite_pages 32
>  innodb_fast_shutdown 1
>  innodb_file_per_table OFF
>  innodb_fill_factor 100
>  innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
>  innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit 1
>  innodb_flush_method O_DIRECT
>  innodb_flush_neighbors 1
>  innodb_flush_sync ON
>  innodb_flushing_avg_loops 30
>  innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
>  innodb_force_recovery 0
>  innodb_fsync_threshold 0
>  innodb_ft_aux_table
>  innodb_ft_cache_size 8000000
>  innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF
>  innodb_ft_enable_stopword ON
>  innodb_ft_max_token_size 84
>  innodb_ft_min_token_size 3
>  innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
>  innodb_ft_result_cache_limit 2000000000
>  innodb_ft_server_stopword_table
>  innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree 2
>  innodb_ft_total_cache_size 640000000
>  innodb_ft_user_stopword_table
>  innodb_idle_flush_pct 100
>  innodb_io_capacity 200
>  innodb_io_capacity_max 2000
>  innodb_lock_wait_timeout 50
>  innodb_log_buffer_size 8388608
>  innodb_log_checksums ON
>  innodb_log_compressed_pages ON
>  innodb_log_file_size 134217728
>  innodb_log_files_in_group 2
>  innodb_log_group_home_dir /rdsdbdata/log/innodb
>  innodb_log_spin_cpu_abs_lwm 80
>  innodb_log_spin_cpu_pct_hwm 50
>  innodb_log_wait_for_flush_spin_hwm 400
>  innodb_log_write_ahead_size 8192
>  innodb_lru_scan_depth 1024
>  innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct 90.000000
>  innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm 10.000000
>  innodb_max_purge_lag 0
>  innodb_max_purge_lag_delay 0
>  innodb_max_undo_log_size 1073741824
>  innodb_monitor_disable
>  innodb_monitor_enable
>  innodb_monitor_reset
>  innodb_monitor_reset_all
>  innodb_numa_interleave OFF
>  innodb_old_blocks_pct 37
>  innodb_old_blocks_time 1000
>  innodb_online_alter_log_max_size 134217728
>  innodb_open_files 300
>  innodb_optimize_fulltext_only OFF
>  innodb_page_cleaners 4
>  innodb_page_size 16384
>  innodb_parallel_read_threads 4
>  innodb_print_all_deadlocks OFF
>  innodb_print_ddl_logs OFF
>  innodb_purge_batch_size 300
>  innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency 128
>  innodb_purge_threads 1
>  innodb_random_read_ahead OFF
>  innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
>  innodb_read_io_threads 4
>  innodb_read_only OFF
>  innodb_redo_log_archive_dirs
>  innodb_redo_log_encrypt OFF
>  innodb_replication_delay 0
>  innodb_rollback_on_timeout OFF
>  innodb_rollback_segments 128
>  innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
>  innodb_spin_wait_delay 6
>  innodb_spin_wait_pause_multiplier 50
>  innodb_stats_auto_recalc ON
>  innodb_stats_include_delete_marked OFF
>  innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
>  innodb_stats_on_metadata OFF
>  innodb_stats_persistent ON
>  innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages 20
>  innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
>  innodb_status_output OFF
>  innodb_status_output_locks OFF
>  innodb_strict_mode ON
>  innodb_sync_array_size 1
>  innodb_sync_spin_loops 30
>  innodb_table_locks ON
>  innodb_temp_data_file_path ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
>  innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir ./#innodb_temp/
>  innodb_thread_concurrency 0
>  innodb_thread_sleep_delay 10000
>  innodb_tmpdir
>  innodb_undo_directory ./
>  innodb_undo_log_encrypt OFF
>  innodb_undo_log_truncate ON
>  innodb_undo_tablespaces 2
>  innodb_use_native_aio ON
>  innodb_validate_tablespace_paths ON
>  innodb_version 8.0.21
>  innodb_write_io_threads 4
>  insert_id 0
>  interactive_timeout 28800
>  internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine TempTable
>  join_buffer_size 262144
>  keep_files_on_create OFF
>  key_buffer_size 16777216
>  key_cache_age_threshold 300
>  key_cache_block_size 1024
>  key_cache_division_limit 100
>  keyring_operations ON
>  large_files_support ON
>  large_page_size 0
>  large_pages OFF
>  last_insert_id 0
>  lc_messages en_US
>  lc_messages_dir /rdsdbbin/mysql-8.0.21.R8/share/
>  lc_time_names en_US
>  license GPL
>  local_infile ON
>  lock_wait_timeout 31536000
>  locked_in_memory OFF
>  log_bin ON
>  log_bin_basename /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog
>  log_bin_index /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog.index
>  log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
>  log_bin_use_v1_row_events OFF
>  log_error /rdsdbdata/log/error/mysql-error.log
>  log_error_services log_filter_internal; log_sink_internal
>  log_error_suppression_list
>  log_error_verbosity 3
>  log_output TABLE
>  log_queries_not_using_indexes OFF
>  log_raw OFF
>  log_slave_updates ON
>  log_slow_admin_statements OFF
>  log_slow_extra OFF
>  log_slow_slave_statements OFF
>  log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog OFF
>  log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes 0
>  log_timestamps UTC
>  long_query_time 5.000000
>  low_priority_updates OFF
>  lower_case_file_system OFF
>  lower_case_table_names 0
>  mandatory_roles
>  master_info_repository TABLE
>  master_verify_checksum OFF
>  max_allowed_packet 16777216
>  max_binlog_cache_size 18446744073709547520
>  max_binlog_size 134217728
>  max_binlog_stmt_cache_size 18446744073709547520
>  max_connect_errors 100
>  max_connections 640
>  max_delayed_threads 20
>  max_digest_length 1024
>  max_error_count 1024
>  max_execution_time 0
>  max_heap_table_size 67108864
>  max_insert_delayed_threads 20
>  max_join_size 18446744073709551615
>  max_length_for_sort_data 4096
>  max_points_in_geometry 65536
>  max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
>  max_relay_log_size 0
>  max_seeks_for_key 18446744073709551615
>  max_sort_length 1024
>  max_sp_recursion_depth 0
>  max_user_connections 0
>  max_write_lock_count 18446744073709551615
>  min_examined_row_limit 0
>  myisam_data_pointer_size 6
>  myisam_max_sort_file_size 9223372036853727232
>  myisam_mmap_size 18446744073709551615
>  myisam_recover_options OFF
>  myisam_repair_threads 1
>  myisam_sort_buffer_size 8388608
>  myisam_stats_method nulls_unequal
>  myisam_use_mmap OFF
>  mysql_native_password_proxy_users OFF
>  net_buffer_length 16384
>  net_read_timeout 30
>  net_retry_count 10
>  net_write_timeout 60
>  new OFF
>  ngram_token_size 2
>  offline_mode OFF
>  old OFF
>  old_alter_table OFF
>  open_files_limit 65535
>  optimizer_prune_level 1
>  optimizer_search_depth 62
>  optimizer_switch index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_so...
>  optimizer_trace enabled=off,one_line=off
>  optimizer_trace_features greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=...
>  optimizer_trace_limit 1
>  optimizer_trace_max_mem_size 1048576
>  optimizer_trace_offset -1
>  original_commit_timestamp 36028797018963968
>  original_server_version 999999
>  parser_max_mem_size 18446744073709551615
>  partial_revokes OFF
>  password_history 0
>  password_require_current OFF
>  password_reuse_interval 0
>  performance_schema ON
>  performance_schema_accounts_size -1
>  performance_schema_digests_size 10000
>  performance_schema_error_size 4772
>  performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size 10000
>  performance_schema_events_stages_history_size 10
>  performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_... 10000
>  performance_schema_events_statements_history_size 10
>  performance_schema_events_transactions_history_lon... 10000
>  performance_schema_events_transactions_history_siz... 10
>  performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size 10000
>  performance_schema_events_waits_history_size 10
>  performance_schema_hosts_size -1
>  performance_schema_max_cond_classes 100
>  performance_schema_max_cond_instances -1
>  performance_schema_max_digest_length 1024
>  performance_schema_max_digest_sample_age 60
>  performance_schema_max_file_classes 80
>  performance_schema_max_file_handles 32768
>  performance_schema_max_file_instances -1
>  performance_schema_max_index_stat -1
>  performance_schema_max_memory_classes 450
>  performance_schema_max_metadata_locks -1
>  performance_schema_max_mutex_classes 300
>  performance_schema_max_mutex_instances -1
>  performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instanc... -1
>  performance_schema_max_program_instances -1
>  performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes 60
>  performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances -1
>  performance_schema_max_socket_classes 10
>  performance_schema_max_socket_instances -1
>  performance_schema_max_sql_text_length 1024
>  performance_schema_max_stage_classes 175
>  performance_schema_max_statement_classes 218
>  performance_schema_max_statement_stack 10
>  performance_schema_max_table_handles -1
>  performance_schema_max_table_instances -1
>  performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat -1
>  performance_schema_max_thread_classes 100
>  performance_schema_max_thread_instances -1
>  performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size 512
>  performance_schema_setup_actors_size -1
>  performance_schema_setup_objects_size -1
>  performance_schema_users_size -1
>  persist_only_admin_x509_subject
>  persisted_globals_load OFF
>  pid_file /rdsdbdata/log/mysql-3306.pid
>  plugin_dir /rdsdbbin/mysql-8.0.21.R8/lib/plugin/
>  port 3306
>  preload_buffer_size 32768
>  print_identified_with_as_hex OFF
>  profiling OFF
>  profiling_history_size 15
>  protocol_compression_algorithms zlib,zstd,uncompressed
>  protocol_version 10
>  proxy_user
>  pseudo_slave_mode OFF
>  pseudo_thread_id 82683823
>  query_alloc_block_size 8192
>  query_prealloc_size 8192
>  rand_seed1 0
>  rand_seed2 0
>  range_alloc_block_size 4096
>  range_optimizer_max_mem_size 8388608
>  rbr_exec_mode STRICT
>  read_buffer_size 262144
>  read_only OFF
>  read_rnd_buffer_size 524288
>  regexp_stack_limit 8000000
>  regexp_time_limit 32
>  relay_log /rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog
>  relay_log_basename /rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog
>  relay_log_index /rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog.index
>  relay_log_info_file relay-log.info
>  relay_log_info_repository TABLE
>  relay_log_purge ON
>  relay_log_recovery ON
>  relay_log_space_limit 0
>  report_host
>  report_password
>  report_port 3306
>  report_user
>  require_row_format OFF
>  require_secure_transport OFF
>  resultset_metadata FULL
>  rpl_read_size 8192
>  rpl_stop_slave_timeout 31536000
>  schema_definition_cache 256
>  secondary_engine_cost_threshold 100000.000000
>  secure_file_priv /tmp/
>  server_id 75552514
>  server_id_bits 32
>  server_uuid a467d598-62c5-11eb-9b40-06eec9903d59
>  session_track_gtids OFF
>  session_track_schema ON
>  session_track_state_change OFF
>  session_track_system_variables time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,characte...
>  session_track_transaction_info OFF
>  sha256_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys ON
>  sha256_password_private_key_path private_key.pem
>  sha256_password_proxy_users OFF
>  sha256_password_public_key_path public_key.pem
>  show_create_table_skip_secondary_engine OFF
>  show_create_table_verbosity OFF
>  show_old_temporals OFF
>  skip_external_locking ON
>  skip_name_resolve OFF
>  skip_networking OFF
>  skip_show_database OFF
>  slave_allow_batching OFF
>  slave_checkpoint_group 512
>  slave_checkpoint_period 300
>  slave_compressed_protocol OFF
>  slave_exec_mode IDEMPOTENT
>  slave_load_tmpdir /tmp
>  slave_max_allowed_packet 1073741824
>  slave_net_timeout 60
>  slave_parallel_type DATABASE
>  slave_parallel_workers 0
>  slave_pending_jobs_size_max 134217728
>  slave_preserve_commit_order OFF
>  slave_rows_search_algorithms INDEX_SCAN,HASH_SCAN
>  slave_skip_errors OFF
>  slave_sql_verify_checksum ON
>  slave_transaction_retries 10
>  slave_type_conversions
>  slow_launch_time 10
>  slow_query_log ON
>  slow_query_log_file /rdsdbdata/log/slowquery/mysql-slowquery.log
>  socket /tmp/mysql.sock
>  sort_buffer_size 524288
>  sql_auto_is_null OFF
>  sql_big_selects ON
>  sql_buffer_result OFF
>  sql_log_bin ON
>  sql_log_off OFF
>  sql_mode NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
>  sql_notes ON
>  sql_quote_show_create ON
>  sql_require_primary_key OFF
>  sql_safe_updates OFF
>  sql_select_limit 18446744073709551615
>  sql_slave_skip_counter 0
>  sql_warnings OFF
>  ssl_ca /rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/ca-cert.pem
>  ssl_capath
>  ssl_cert /rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/server-cert.pem
>  ssl_cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-S...
>  ssl_crl
>  ssl_crlpath
>  ssl_fips_mode OFF
>  ssl_key /rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/server-key.pem
>  stored_program_cache 256
>  stored_program_definition_cache 256
>  super_read_only OFF
>  sync_binlog 1
>  sync_master_info 10000
>  sync_relay_log 10000
>  sync_relay_log_info 10000
>  system_time_zone UTC
>  table_definition_cache 10000
>  table_encryption_privilege_check OFF
>  table_open_cache 30000
>  table_open_cache_instances 16
>  tablespace_definition_cache 256
>  temptable_max_ram 1073741824
>  temptable_use_mmap ON
>  thread_cache_size 14
>  thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
>  thread_stack 262144
>  time_zone UTC
>  timestamp 1615888520.038063
>  tls_ciphersuites
>  tls_version TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
>  tmp_table_size 67108864
>  tmpdir /rdsdbdata/tmp
>  transaction_alloc_block_size 8192
>  transaction_allow_batching OFF
>  transaction_isolation REPEATABLE-READ
>  transaction_prealloc_size 4096
>  transaction_read_only OFF
>  transaction_write_set_extraction XXHASH64
>  unique_checks ON
>  updatable_views_with_limit YES
>  use_secondary_engine ON
>  version 8.0.21
>  version_comment Source distribution
>  version_compile_machine x86_64
>  version_compile_os Linux
>  version_compile_zlib 1.2.11
>  wait_timeout 28800
>  warning_count 0
>  windowing_use_high_precision ON

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for active apps, 
ulimit -a       Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: You may need to ask your AWS provider to provide the reports from the OS Command Prompt.

Comment: Please in your my.cnf [mysqld] section have a line for log_slow_extra=ON - then after 24 hours of UPTIME, post last 400 lines of your slow_query_log output file for analysis.  Are you aware t2 and t3 should NOT be used for AWS production systems?  See following URL -  https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/

Comment: Why use `LOCK TABLES`?  That is almost always wrong for InnoDB tables.  It would be nice to see the full queries for any query taking more than 10 seconds.

Comment: We changed the instance size twice to next m generation with 8gb and another one to 4vCpu's 16gb. Raising amount of memory didn't radically help, but number of vCpu's did the job and all weird queries are gone and DB started respond exactly as we expected.

Regarding locking tables — those tables were used by app and just rarely were locked by cron jobs. But anyway we reworked the code to not use locking tables. Doesn't help at all.

Upgrade storage to provisioned 1000 iops one doesn't help neither.